# предлог к топониму

Tags: предлоги, топонимика

Населенный пункт называется станция Мочище, как говорить правильно НА Мочище или В Мочище?

Comment: Населённый пункт (город или посёлок, Автору виднее) называется Мочище, станцией — место остановки транспорта.

Answer (score 2):

В этом топониме очень нестандартная трактовка видового наименования (станция с населением, площадью, образовательными и медицинскими учреждениями, да ещё в составе Станционного сельсовета). Поэтому предлог "**на**" лучше употреблять вместе с наименованием "станция" и только в контекстах, не вызывающих вопросов у непосвящённых (не связанных с "населением станции", напр. в значении железнодорожного узла), а предлог "**в**" употреблять в случаях подразумеваемой общей трактовки Мочища как "населённого пункта".

Answer (score 0):

По употреблению топонима на официальных сайтах можно сделать вывод, что склонению слово не подвергается:  «Как доехать из Мочище в Новосибирск»; Трасса с Мочище до Новосибирска» и т. д.

Если имеется в виду направление движения — *на Мочище*, если — город как конечный пункт поездки, то *в Мочище*.

Comment: По-разному употреляют. Возможно, и есть местная тенденция, подобная несклонению Бологого. https://bus.tutu.ru/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5_1339250/ Пример из книги: https://books.google.ru/books?id=GW-gqCbYD-4C&pg=PT46&lpg=PT46&dq=из++мочища&source=bl&ots=j9xiS9ffwK&sig=p82ug-3gqWkYqCy_T55YjZT4uN0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3ydutnM7ZAhXF1iwKHY1LAyw4ChDoAQgwMAE#v=onepage&q=из мочища&f=false